# Crystal reports 2011 Math operations on running total fields

Tags: crystal-reports

Been trying to do this for hours, so would very much appreciate an answer.  Google apparently hasn't heard this question before; in fact, I could find very little information on this subject anywhere, including in the Crystal reports help functions.

I have three running total fields in a Crystal Reports 2011 report.  I need to add two of them together and then divide that sum by a third running total field.

Here is what I have in the formula field I have created in order to do this:

(Sum(rtotal1))+(Sum(rtotal2))/(Sum(rtotal3))

The error I continue to get is:  **The ) is missing**

Can anyone tell me the correct syntax for how to do this (aggravatingly simple) operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure what your running totals are (sum, count, etc.), but you shouldn't have to specify sum in your formula. I did a quick mock-up with 3 running total fields, each one a sum of a value. the resulting formula looks like this:

```
({#RTotal0} + {#RTotal1})/{#RTotal2}
```

I'm not sure if the brackets are needed, but since you want to add RTotal0 and RTotal1 first and then divide that result by RTotal2, I advise to put them in.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is correct and worked.  Some things to check for anyone else having this problem:  Make sure you're trying to do this as a formula field and not as another running total, and don't try working with Crystal for more than 8 hours at a time because then you start making mistakes like this.